# VHDL signal dimension issue when reducing a generic value down to 0

Tags: vhdl, fpga

How can one handle this case:

```
entity foo is
    generic (
        num_instances : natural := 8
    );
    port (
        data_in_per_instance : in std_logic_vector(num_instances-1 downto 0);
        data_out_per_instance : out std_logic_vector(num_instances-1 downto 0)
    );
end foo;

architecture bar of foo is

    component do_stuff is
        port(
            din : in std_logic;
            dout : out std_logic
        );
    end component do_stuff;

    signal sig_per_instance : std_logic_vector(num_instances-1 downto 0);

begin

L1: for i in 0 to num_instances-1 generate
    L2: do_stuff
        port map(
            din => data_in_per_instance(i),
            dout => data_out_per_instance(i)
        );
end generate;

end bar;
```

The problem here is that if `num_instances` is reduced to 0 there will be an error when the signal ranges `(num_instances-1 downto 0)`  are evaluated....
Is there an elegant way around this? All I can come up with is using a function like `max(num_instances-1,0)` to prevent this problem (but then synthesis may not give me exactly what I want, i.e. nothing).
Is there some way to handle this case a little more seamless?

Comment: Hmm, Altera's tools whine about the empty range and then ignore it.  Having the "correct" solution is nicer though.

Comment: Ditto Xilinx tools when I ran into the same issue.

Comment: Only two minor VHDL errors in your code, mode out for port declaration data_out_per_instance and "end should be followed by component".  Throw in missing context declarations and a test bench, it analyzes, elaborates and simulates for num_instances 0 and 8.  When 0 no signal assignments occur. Using ghdl and a ghw dumpfile format to convey the 0 case waveform to gtkwave causes a gtkwave error. The question is how to prevent your synthesis tool from barfing on something that's not a VHDL problem, it's not properly dealing with a NULL range. There are no signals there nor instances.

Comment: And about now you could could see the use for synthesis directives capable of evaluating num_instances. The problem is that generics are elaboration time evaluated, and you really want something to tell your synthesis tool to not traverse the part of the network containing no instances and associated signals.  It says the solution isn't in VHDL space without decorating the particular portion of the design specification with synthesis directives when the generic is set to 0.  The problem with NULL range vectors is recursive upward so you can't simply wrap it all with a generate statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer is to wrap the for-generate statement in an if-generate, `if num_instances /= 0 generate ...` Unfortunately if-generates have no else part, however there is nothing to stop you adding a second `if num_instances = 0 generate ...` statement to handle that special case.

Alternatively you can wrap the problem part of the for-generate using if-generate.

EDIT: re the need for a correct signal declaration guarded by the `if ... generate`.

AHA! You may have discovered a legitimate use for VHDL's (in my experience) rarely used  "block" statement!

A block statement may contain signal declarations, and can be wrapped in a generate.

So this is valid VHDL:

```
Normality : block is
   -- signal declarations here
begin
   -- concurrent code here
end block Normality;
```

and it can be legally wrapped in a generate statement...

Comment: Thanks, but in the example above there is still a signal declaration using the invalid range (after the component declaration) which remains unhandled by the solution you suggest.

Comment: I have to admit I have rarely used the block statement in VHDL thus far, i.e. never really =)

Comment: @damage: Neither has anyone else :)

Answer (score 1):

A `std_logic_vector` with an empty range (for example `3 downto 4`) is perfectly legitimate - it's called a "null range" by the LRM.  If you create one, then (at least with Modelsim) you will get warnings, which is usually considered poor form.  To eliminate those, then Brian's `block` suggestion is what you'll have do.

Similarly the `for..generate` will result in an empty loop and no instances.  No warnings for this.

I'm intrigued why you'd want a block with no instances in?  I'd make `num_instances` a `positive` to force at least one of them, but that may not actually what you want!